# Apply fade in to Javascript backgroundImage change

Tags: javascript

This is my code which changes the background

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/space1.jpg)";
```

How would I add an opacity transition to this in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I have updatet this main comment so you have the complete answer :)

You cannot easily do that to the body background. You can however give the effect of this by adding a div, for instance like this (z-index -1 does the 'trick'):

```
<body>
  <div id="js_background_filler" class="background_filler"></div>
... rest of your body ...
```

Then in your style/css:

```
.background_filler {
  background-image: url(img/space1);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.2;
  will-change: opacity;
}

.background_filler--animate {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s ease-in alternate infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s ease-in alternate infinite;
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in alternate infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

You probably have a JavaScript function somewhere which you want to background to trigger animating with, expand it with something like:

```
var $element = document.getElementById('js_background_filler');
$element.classList.add("background_filler--animate");
```

You can fiddle around with the `animation: fadein 2s ease-in alternate infinite;` (for instance make it slow by setting it to 20s (seconds)).

Comment: Looks great would that Animation call when the background image was changed?

Comment: Actually no I did mean an animated background. So that when the function is triggered, the background image changes but with a fade in :)

Comment: this will just 'always' animate (with any background, even if you change the background-image in css). 

If you don't want this: You can change this by 'adding a classname' when you want the animation to start for instance (or set it via javascript). Just move the animation-property to a new classname (eg `. background_filler--animation { animation-property-here .. }`) and if you want it to start animating, just set the div's classname to include that `background_filler--animate`.

Comment: I've updatet the main story to include the script example as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `css`. It's more simply.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src ="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTDYDnkDr8JO6eh9_uXwwZpbHAkLbj02Tsdj3Iy2odb5vPEsXhBA";
```

```css
.item-fade{
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.item-fade:hover{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<span>
   <img class="hover item-fade" src="" />
</span>
```